# pytorch model loading and prediction, AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'predict'

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, pytorch

```
model = torch.load('/home/ofsdms/san_mrc/checkpoint/best_v1_checkpoint.pt', map_location='cpu')
results, labels = predict_function(model, dev_data, version)

> /home/ofsdms/san_mrc/my_utils/data_utils.py(34)predict_squad()
-> phrase, spans, scores = model.predict(batch)
(Pdb) n
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

How do I load  a saved checkpoint of pytorch model, and use the same for prediction. I have the model saved in .pt extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the checkpoint you save is usually a [`state_dict`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.state_dict):  a dictionary containing the values of the trained weights - but **not** the actual architecture of the net. The actual computational graph/architecture of the net is described as a python class (derived from [`nn.Module`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module)).
To use a trained model you need:

1. Instantiate a `model` from the class implementing the computational graph.
2. Load the saved `state_dict` to that instance:

   ```
   model.load_state_dict(torch.load('/home/ofsdms/san_mrc/checkpoint/best_v1_checkpoint.pt', map_location='cpu')
   ```

Comment: I have used torch.load to do a full model load, in my case,    model = DocReaderModel(opt, embedding)  model_file_2 = os.path.join(model_dir, 'checkpoint_{}_epoch_{}_full_model.pt'.format(version, epoch)), torch.save(model, model_file_2)